# how to edit a huge text file inline

Tags: linux, text

I have a huge text file(100GB) that requires editing a single line on linux.
Clearly this can't be done with a regular text editor.
Is there a way to do this?  basically jumps to the nth line and then edit it and then save it back.

Comment: More info about what you want to edit, pattern etc... would be better. `sed` is one option for editing a particular line.

Comment: To my understanding, it's impossible without opening the file because how the file is stored on disk is unknown prior to opening.

Comment: You could `split` the file, edit the relevant chunk, and use `cat` to rebuild the huge file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'sed' stream editor to edit files of arbitrary size as it does not need to load the entire file in at once. for instance:

```
  sed '54 s/[0-9][0-9]*/gone/' < file_in.txt > file_out.txt
```

will replace a number found on line 54 with the word 'gone'.

It also supports editing a file in place with the '-i' option, but I have never tried it on a hundred gigabyte file. No reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: `-i` option to sed will create a tmp file, and then when complete, rename that tmp file to the original filename. No std unix text utility can modify a file in place, it will always create a 2nd copy, so OP will require an extra 100GB space for that tmp file. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

If you known the exactly byte offset of the location to edit, and the edition does not change the length of the line, then you could `fseek()` to the line, read the line in, change it and then write out.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a 6000 line 'example.txt' and you want to change 3001th line to 'hello world'.

```
head -n 3000 example.txt > tmp.txt
echo 'hello world' >> tmp.txt
tail -n 2999 example.txt >> tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt example.txt
```